# javascript, php, mysql and settimeout

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, settimeout

I am newer programming web page, and i have a problem whit these languages.
I have a init() function with javascript and php code (to access to mysql)
This funcion calls to a refresh() function which access to mysql and at the end of this function calls to settimeout(refresh();5000) to execute the funcion again each 5 seconds.
But the problem i have detected is that php is executed only once, however javascript is executed again and again. 
Someone knows why php is only executed once??

thanks a lot

Comment: You probably wont get much help with this questions as it is now. I suggest you read this first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please post your code here. I dont think it is possible to answer your problem without knowing what is your code exactly

Comment: Why you don't read a lot of books and tutorials before trying to do something without knowing the absolute basics ? Development takes years to learn. You'll only have problems after problems until you really really learn it.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words
Php is executed in server whereas javascript is client side language. Whenever you load webpage it is parsed at server side and then it is displayed at your browser. thus the operations in php are already executed and there is no way to perform same php operation again once the page loads.

Those php operations can be performed one again only by
1. reloading whole webpage
2. using asynchronous method such as ajax, which can be used to interact with the server side to perform operation and bring results back to client side even after the page is loaded.

Hope this answer your queries